# Jumping from a try block to a finally block

Tags: java

I'm trying to do the following :

```
String txt = "begin\n";

try{

    // some stuff

    if(some condition)
        JUMP TO FINALLY CODE

    // some other stuff

} finally {

    String txt += "end\n";
    return txt;

}
```

Is there a way to implement `JUMP TO FINALLY CODE` without raising an exception (raising an exception wouldn't look clean in my opinion)

Comment: Basic solution: if(! some condition){// all after statements} then it automatically jump to finally

Answer (score 12, accepted):

yes one way is to just `return` from the method like this

```
String txt = "begin\n";

    try{

        // some stuff

        if(some condition)
            return;

        // some other stuff

    } finally {

        String txt += "end\n";

    }
```

Comment: Hmm, you'll miss the part after `finally`. The method will halt after running `finally` code block.

Comment: Good point Dmitry, but if the `return` in the `if` condition makes the jump to the finally code, it's fine for me !

Comment: Little trick : this code appears in a `toString()` method. What if I would like to return something in the `finally` block ? Would the return in the `if` be discarded ? In any case, it wouldn't look clear to the reader...

Comment: @sol4me I am confused let suppose if method return type is void then how it would work ?

Comment: @Backslash36 - Whatever you return in the *finall* block will be returned. So, the value of the `if` condition is not returned.

Comment: The above only works if you want to return from the function. If you have code following the try block, this doesn't work.
Basically we to answer the question of how to go to the finally block generally speaking.

Answer (score 6):

No need of having any method to jump to `finally` since here always `finally` block execute. Whether or not there is an `Exception`.

You can just use a `return` if you don't want to execute the line of codes bellow something

```
 try {
      if(isThisShouldReturn()){
          return; // when if satisfied will return from try
      } else {
          // do the stuff
      }
  }finally {
      System.out.println("come to finally");
  }
```

Comment: Then he should encapsulate the other code in an else-branch.

Comment: I have many ifs inside the try block, and I'd like to keep the code readable. The return keyword shall do the trick !

Comment: @Ruchitra I am confused, let suppose if method return type is void then how it would work ?

Comment: @VikasVerma return type is not considering here. you can use `return` keyword inside the method return type as void. Just try.`public void tryThis(){
        boolean status = true;
        try {
            if (status) {
                System.out.println(status);
                return;
            } else {
                // do the stuff
            }
            System.out.println(status);
        } finally {
            System.out.println("come to finally");
        }
    }`

Comment: @VikasVerma above peace of code it self has the answer. Now if condition match non of the code out side if else will execute.

Comment: but let suppose I've code void go(){ return; } what that it mean ?

Comment: @VikasVerma no one want to right pointless code. the meaning of the code come up with how you write the code. In this case no sense.

Answer (score 3):

My approach would be to negate the condition:

```
String txt = "begin\n";

try{        
    // some stuff

    if(!someCondition) {
        // some other stuff
    }

} finally {     
    String txt += "end\n";
}
```

This would have the intended behaviour for your example.

Comment: @VikasVerma Sorry, didn't see that. You wrote your comment while I was writing my answer.

Comment: @Vikas Verma the answer is correct why did you downvote it? You could have answered if you wanted...

Comment: @VikasVerma - Nobody asked you to write that answer as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a block label combined with a break; something like:

```
end_try: try {
  ...
  break end_try;
  ...
} finally {
  ...
}
```

or:

```
try {
  ...
  end_try: {
     break end_try;
  }

} finally {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

//Throw an exception from try block or..
//use return call:

```
try
{
  if(true condition)
  {
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    //false condition do work....
  }
}

finally
{
   //always executed.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess return and by throwing exception are the only two ways you can reach out to a finally block from the try block.

Comment: No it is not. Whether or not there is an Exception finally block execute